# How to self-reference NodeJS Module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have a module that I'm exporting. I need one function to call another function. Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do.

```
module.exports = {
  isEven: (number) => {
    return (number%2 == 0)
  },
  isTenEven: () => {
    return isEven(10)
  }
}
```

The code above throws `isEven is not defined` when `moduleName.isTenEven()` is called.

It makes sense why it fails. But how would you rewrite it? (While maintaining the singleton pattern)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the functions first, then export them:

```js
const isEven = (number) => number % 2 === 0
const isTenEven = () => isEven(10)

module.exports = {
  isEven,
  isTenEven
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The object is only used to group the functions together. There's nothing really OO about it so define the functions separately. Construct the object at the end.

```
const isEven = number => number % 2 === 0;
const isTenEven = () => isEven(10);
module.exports = { isEven, isTenEven };
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just do this? Define then export.

```
const isEven = number => number % 2 === 0;

module.exports = {
  isEven,
  isTenEven: () => isEven(10)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add one more solution to the mix.  You don't have to define the function elsewhere.  Since the object declaration is complete before the function gets called, you can refer to it via `module.exports` or via `exports` like this:

```
module.exports = exports = {
  isEven: (number) => {
    return (number%2 === 0)
  },
  isTenEven: () => {
    return exports.isEven(10)
  }
}
```

If you were doing this in a lot of methods, you could define a shorter variable name for the exported object and refer to it.

Comment: In [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), if the only statement in the body is a return statement, you can remove the brackets around it. If the arrow function only has just a single parameter, you can also remove the parenthesis surround it. So, for example, your isEven could be rewritten like this: `isEven: number => number % 2 === 0`. Should almost always be using strong equality `===` over `==`, and avoid type coercion, particularly in a case like this where you're sure of the data types on both side of the operator.

Comment: @StephenMIrving - Yes, I know that.  I just kept with the format that the OP used.  It is a personal style choice whether you remove the braces (just like with a single statement `if`) and whether you surround the single argument with `()`.  I stayed with the style that the OP themselves chose.  I did change the `==` to `===` as that is the best choice here (something I didn't notice since it wasn't the point of the answer).

Comment: Ya I know the thing about arrow function formatting is a style choice, just wanted to let you know in case you were not aware. 

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford Babel or a version of Node.js that supports import/export statements you could also do:

```js
export const isEven = num => num % 2 === 0;
export const isTenEven = () => isEven(10);
```

Answer (score -3):

Inside JS object literal using `this` refers to the object itself so you can have:

```
module.exports = {
  isEven: (number) => {
    return (number%2 == 0)
  },
  isTenEven: function () {
    return this.isEven(10)
  }
}
```

Comment: No. Arrow functions inherit `this` from the lexical scope they are defined in. They don't have their own `this` value.

Comment: Hey aivo. I tried that before asking. It doesn't work.

Comment: Yup, missed that initially and edited right after. It should work.

Comment: This is less safe then the solutions proposed by the other answers since the function might get separated from the object (e.g. `const { isEven, isTenEven } = require("./someModule.js");`)

Comment: True. But since the question was "How to self-reference NodeJS Module", it is still an accurate answer.

Comment: As @Quentin said, when you do `const {isTenEven} = require('./someModule')` then `this` won't be referencing the module anymore.